# How to get readable text on the glass (wpf)

Tags: wpf, user-interface

Here are two screenshots:

A full-glass window over white background:
http://trotsenko.com.ua/stackoverflow/2010_01_13%20Glass%20Window%20over%20a%20white%20background.png

The same full-glass window over back background:
http://trotsenko.com.ua/stackoverflow/2010_01_13%20The%20same%20Glass%20Window%20over%20a%20Black%20background.png

**The question** is: in **WPF**, how do I use `TextBlock` so that it will be readable on the glass?

---

I already tried 
`<DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" BlurRadius="20" Color="White"/>` with no acceptable success. (Maybe I did smth wrong ?)

I didn't succeed with `<OuterGlowBitmapEffect/>` (I think, because bitmap effects are now deprecated. Did I do smth wrong?)

Comment: or... how does Windows output header on the window ?

Comment: 20 is a very large blur radius - have you tried smaller values?

Comment: Yes, I began with smaller values.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the native DrawThemeTextEx() method in dwmapi.dll, but I don't know how to do this in WPF. All examples I found were using WinForms.