# How to use DrawThemeTextEx in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, windows, aero

I'm working on an application that displays text on Aero Glass. To make it readable I used a OuterGlowBitmapEffect, but, as also described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059381/how-to-get-readable-text-on-the-glass-wpf/) this is no longer possible in .NET 4 and the DropShadowEffect won't work for Glass either.

While searching for a solution I came across the native DrawThemeTextEx in DWMApi, but all examples I found were for WinForms and not for WPF.

So how can you use this in WPF?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am also trying to use DrawThemeTextEx however I can not locate any samples that use this along with the correct system fonts.

The following effect in .NET 4 is close to the Aero glass text and replaces the BitmapEffects.

```
   <Decorator>
       <Decorator.Effect>
           <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10" Color="White" ShadowDepth="0" />
       </Decorator.Effect>
   </Decorator>
```